# Default iPhone HTML5 audio player overrides mobile theme width

Tags: iphone, css, html5-audio

I am setting up a static blog for the music that I write. My music is played using HTML5 audio and the default audio controls for every browser. This works well on a desktop but when displaying on the iPhone browser the mobile theme is overridden and the width is increased to  make the page much wider than the CSS. The audio player element is also misaligned.

[image: iPhone screen with width too large]

If I view a blog post which doesn't have an audio player then it looks correct, like this:

[image: iPhone screen with width correct]

The website is at `http://108.171.179.41/` as I haven't migrated the DNS records from my old blog yet. In the future it will be at danielcompton.net

Does anyone know why the display of my website is odd when viewing on iPhone?

Comment: It's currently displaying the standard iOs player and the width seem not to be so large, post the screenshot of the problem.